On time arrow and coordinate change in General relativity
This may be a silly question but I would like to have things cleared up once and for all in my head.
I will take the example of a Schwarzschild black hole as a solution to vacuum Einstein Field Equations. The Schwarzschild coordinates are for the faraway observer and are static with respect to the black hole. Now, we know the horizon is a coordinate singularity, and that we can get rid of it by a suitable change of coordinate (like the Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates for example). This change of coordinate allows us to find that an infalling observer will cross the horizon in finite proper time.
Now the problem with this: we know time is a dimension in which one ought to go in one direction only. Although General Relativity says nothing about the arrow of time, we know there is an arrow of time, at least in a standard setup and without quantum mechanics. The fact that time has an arrow means that the proper time $\tau$ on a worldline is not a cardinal number in the mathematical sense, it is an ordinal number.
If, for the Schwarzschild observer, the event "the infalling worldline crosses the horizon" is at $t = \omega$, then the time $t=\omega+a$ corresponds (again for the Schwarzschild observer) to the infalling observer moving towards the singularity. BUT, we know that $\omega$ is the ordinal we associate to $\infty \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}$. This means that we literally count past infinity when doing a change of coordinate because otherwise, we would have to cut the Eddington-Finkelstein worldline (the worldline of the infalling observer) precisely when it crosses the horizon.
So my question is: Is General Relativity compatible with an "arrow of time"? That is to say, "Should we adapt the range of the time parameter depending on the coordinate system so that every type of worldlines agrees"?
To me, the "ordinal numbers labeling time events" is an overlooked thing precisely because General Relativity says nothing about the arrow of time. But we know there is one, hence my question.
